# Using spring form tag inside a custom JSTL library

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, jstl

I need to create a custom JSTL tag which wraps multiple spring form tags. A single tag which produces the below content with custom attribute values as  well.

```
       <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-6 cal-xs-12">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="statusCode">Employee Status Code: </label>
                <form:input path="statusCode" class="form-control" id="statusCode" value="${statusCode}" />
            </div>
        </div>
```

Is this achievable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

create a file formInputFiled.tag inside WEB-INF/tags/form directory.

formInputFiled.tag:

```
<%@ taglib prefix="form" uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form" %>
<%@ attribute name="id" required="true" rtexprvalue="true" %>
<%@ attribute name="path" required="true" rtexprvalue="true" %>
<%@ attribute name="label" required="true" rtexprvalue="true" %>
<%@ attribute name="value" required="true" rtexprvalue="true" %>
<%@ attribute name="parentDivClass" required="true" rtexprvalue="true" %>
<%@ attribute name="divClass" required="true" rtexprvalue="true" %>
<%@ attribute name="inputClass" required="true" rtexprvalue="true" %>
<div class="${parentDivClass}">
    <div class="${divClass}">
        <label for="${id}">${label}</label>
        <form:input path="${path}" class="${inputClass}" id="${id}" value="${value}" />
    </div>
</div>
```

Add taglib declaration in your jsp like below:

```
<%@ taglib prefix="form" tagdir="/WEB-INF/tags/form" %>
```

Finally use the new tag like below:

```
<form:formInputFiled id="statusCode" path="statusCode" label="Employee Status Code:" value="${statusCode}" parentDivClass="col-md-4 col-sm-6 cal-xs-12" divClass="form-group" inputClass="form-control"/>
```

Comment: Works like a charm!!

Comment: I'm writing another custom tag for <select>. Do you know how to pass object for 'items' attribute from the page to the custom tag. Currently it is getting the object as a string

Comment: post a new question with the detail.